# uploaded images not getting displayed on google cloud storage using c# but pdf file is ok

Tags: c#, image, rest, google-cloud-storage

I am writing code in c# to upload images on google clould storage all type of files are uploaded successfully, and pdf files are brow-sable also, but when uploading images it seems corrupt file. Now idea what happened use two types of code but no lock.

```
    public string uploadMedia(string FolderNo, string filename, Stream _media)
                {                
                       var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(new FileStream(@"\\files\Shared\application_default_credentials.json", FileMode.Open)).CreateScoped(new string[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadWrite });
                        var client = StorageClient.Create(credential);
                        var bucketName = "******";
                        var obj1 = client.UploadObjectAsync(bucketName, FolderNo + "/" + filename, "image/jpg", _media);
                       return  obj1.Result.Name;
                 }
```

Also used the below code but for image uploading is only not working at all

```
public string uploadMedia(string FolderNo, string filename, Stream _media)
        {
            try
            {
                String serviceAccountEmail = "DDDS-storage@HHS-svm2.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"\\files\Shared\HHHX-4d75037a35bf.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService ss = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "HHS_svm2",
                });

                var fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
                {
                    Bucket = "HHHS",
                    Name = filename,
                    ContentType = "image/png"
                };


                byte[] rf = ReadFully(_media);
                Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload insmedia;
                insmedia = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, fileobj, "tamkeen_svm", new MemoryStream(rf), "image/png");
                insmedia.Upload();
}
```

Comment: `it seems corrupt file.` What brought you to that conclusion?

Comment: Only images which are uploaded having issues (even uploaded images cant be edited so sure it's not in right format). Size is always same. Also I have mentioned that pdf files are opening perfectly after load.  I am not sure may be some additional parameters need to set or is it right to say library from google is buggy for c#

Comment: Any one can help me on this please?

Comment: What kind of image are you uploading? png? jpg? something else?

Comment: I tried both jpg and png, neither worked for me

Comment: Hi  mjwills, do you have any guessing abt the issue

Comment: Alas I do not :(

Comment: Some of the post suggested Sending a multipart upload request, can we say this could be an issue https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload#multipart-file-upload